# Select or create an entity

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I usually find answers to solve my problems after some research, but that is not the case today.

Let's suppose I have 2 entities, "Task" and "TaskCategory", each task has one category.
I want to let my users not only attribute an existing category to their tasks but also create new ones.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php
// TaskCategoryType.php
class TaskCategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }
// Some stuff...
```

and

```
<?php
// TaskType.php

// Some stuff...

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // Add some fields there
            ->add(
                'category',
                TransformableEntityType::class,
                ['class' => 'AppBundle:TaskCategory']
            )
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $task = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();
                if (empty($task['category']['id']) && !empty($task['category']['name'])) {
                    $task['category']['id'] = null;
                    $event->setData($task);
                    $form->remove('category');
                    $form->add('category', TaskCategoryType::class);
                }
            })
        ;
    }

// Some stuff...
```

It works fine for task creation, but when I edit an existing task, it edit the associated TaskCategory instead of creating a new one.
I was trying to force the creation of a new TaskCategory with : $task['category']['id'] = null; but it does not work.

Thanks for your help I'm really stuck :(

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using this form only as an API that's why I have only one 'category' field, otherwise I would have used another 'category_new' field.

Comment: If you are in edit case you get into `if` function ?

Comment: I have no way to tell if it's an edit/creation inside the form.
I get into the if only if category id is not set and category name is set. Which means i'm trying to create a new category.

Comment: Why do not check condition like *!empty($task['category']['id'])* instead of *empty($task['category']['id'])*? If id is not empty (=already exists) it is not come to if-block

Comment: I have to go through the if to replace the existing field with the TaskCategoryType field if the category does not already exist.

The actual problem is that if I wan't to edit an existing task which is already associated with a category, and want to replace that category with a new one, it will just update the name of the current category instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems I finally found something working, it's not pretty, I'm not pretty happy with how it's done but at the moment I have not found any alternative.
If you have a cleaner solution I'll be happy to learn.

```
<?php
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder

        // Some fields...

        ->add(
            'category',
            TransformableEntityType::class,
            ['class' => 'AppBundle:TaskCategory']
        )
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $task = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if (empty($task['category']['id']) && !empty($task['category']['name'])) {
                // If there is no category id but there is a category
                // name it means it is a new category. so replace 
                // the custom entity field with this simple field
                $form->remove('category');
                $form->add('category', TaskCategoryType::class, ['allow_extra_fields' => true]);
            }
        })
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $catForm = $event->getForm()->get('category');
            if ($catForm->has('name') && $catForm->get('name')->getData() !== "") {
                // If there is a category name it means 
                // it is a new category. 
                $category = new TaskCategory(); // Create new category
                $category->setName($catForm->get('name')->getData());
                $task = $event->getData()->setCategory($category);
                $event->setData($task);
            }
        })
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have `cascade-persist` enabled for your association from `Task` to `TaskCategory`. I guess the best work around will be, to use an `autocompleter` which should work as tag based.

The `Transformer` should check with database if given `TaskCategory` is available, else create a new one.

Comment: I was also thinking about using a Transformer for this task. But I think it's not his role to create an entity and moreover if there is a validation error the transformation will take place and create the new entity even if it's not used.
No big deal but something to note!

Comment: Form my last work, I don't think transformer will create a new entry if there is a validation. Probably, I handled it explicitly. I will update you with some code snippet later. But just know, Using a `Transformer` is life saviour. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I missed your comment, I'll gladly see a snippet of your solution if you find it ;-)